# Pass boolean value from parent to child component in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pass boolean value from parent to child component without involving template file. Normal parent to child communication by using template file I'm aware of that, but not getting idea how to communicate without using template class.

This is how I have tried, but I'm not sure this is correct approach or not.

Parent component.ts:

```js
export class ParentComponent{
value1: boolean;

ngOnInit(){
if(condition){
  this.value1=true;
}
}
}
```

Child component.ts:

```js
export class Childcomponent{
  @Input() value1: boolean;
}
```

Comment: why not use template prop though?

Comment: Use @ViewChild . Search the web for examplea

Comment: @Soroush_Neshat ViewChild was introduced in Angular 4, question title says Angular 2 though

Comment: @AyushGupta i cant see angular 2 in question title !

Comment: @Soroush_Neshat Question got edited. I edited again just now to put 2 in there as it matters a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an observable to the parent component.

```
 export class ParentComponent {
      public value$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

      public notifyChild(value: boolean) {
          this.value$.next(value);
      }
 }
```

Inject the parent into the child and subscribe.

```
 export class ChildComponent implmenents OnDestroy {
     private destroyed: Subject = new Subject<void>;
     public constructor(parent: ParentComponent) {
         parent.value$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed)).subscribe((value)=>{ ... });
     }
     public ngOnDestroy() {
          this.destroyed.next();
     }
 }
```